# Tweepy error: unhashable type slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am trying to use the tweepy library to collect some data from twitter to conduct some sentiment analysis.

Here is a sample of the script I am running:

```
import tweepy 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, parser = tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())


# Set search query
searchquery = '"atiku" -filter:retweets'
data = api.search(q = searchquery, count = 100, lang = 'en', result_type = 'mixed')
data_all = list(data.values())[0]
#(data.values())[1])

while (len(data_all) <= 20000):
    time.sleep(5)
    last = data_all[1]['id']
    data = api.search(q = searchquery, count = 100, lang = 'en', result_type = 'mixed', max_id = last)
    data_all += list(data.values())[1][1:]

print(data_all)
```

I have hit a road block in my code, as when I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

I would appreciate any pointers on thos